# Access - Store values in ComboBox to use as parameters in running a query (Run Query Button)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

Form has 2 ComboBox's (boxLaborCore, boxPosition) and a Button (runQuery).  Button built through control wizard, a Run Query button.  Runs the query that has a parameter called LaborCore and Position. Based on the the type of work area / position selected, different skills are displayed in the Select Query.  The query runs fine when I manually type in labor core / position, I want to be able to be able to automate this.

I switched criteria in the query from [Enter labor core] to

```
[Forms]![Form1]![boxLaborCore]
```

as well as from [Enter position] to

```
[Forms]![Form1]![boxPosition]
```

I've read that I need to edit the BoundColumn property in order to store the value.

Can someone point me in the right direction for fixing this?  Would VBA code do the trick using event After_Update?

Do you know what's causing this problem?  My dream form would look something like this: (Step 1) Select the labor core / position in the combobox's (Step 3) Click button that runs query.  Results in a table with the right set of skills for the specified parameters.

SQL code here for the query. 5 tables involved, 2 tbls for laborcore and position, a table for all the possible combinations of laborcore / position called workarea, and a table with all the skills:

```
    SELECT tblWorkArea.ID_WorkArea, tblWorkArea.[Labor Core], tblWorkArea.Position, tblSkills.Wiring, tblSkills.[Wire Type], tblSkills.[Terminal Types], tblSkills.[NEMA Ratings], tblSkills.[UL 508], tblSkills.[Attention to Detail], tblSkills.[Lifting 50lbs], tblSkills.[Knowledge of Procedure], tblSkills.Crimper, tblSkills.[Heat Gun], tblSkills.Screwdriver, tblSkills.Stripper, tblSkills.[Impact Drill], tblSkills.[Radial Saw], tblSkills.Multimeter, tblSkills.[Torque Screwdriver/Wrench], tblSkills.[Tape Measure], tblSkills.Vacuum, tblSkills.[Drill Press], tblSkills.[Jig Saw], tblSkills.[Troubleshooting Components], tblSkills.[Problem Solving], tblSkills.Organization, tblSkills.[Large Panel], tblSkills.[Test Procedures], tblSkills.[Functional Testing], tblSkills.[Writing Test Procedures], tblSkills.[Material Management], tblSkills.[Set Meter Ability], tblSkills.[Tone Generator], tblSkills.[Megger Testing], tblSkills.[Network Tracer], tblSkills.Components, tblSkills.Fuses, tblSkills.[Heat Shrink Color Codes], tblSkills.[Proper Lug or Crimping], tblSkills.[Resistors Knowledge], tblSkills.Oscilloscopes, tblSkills.Waveforms, tblSkills.[Voltage Separation], tblSkills.[Skill x_Stapling]

    FROM ((tblLaborCore INNER JOIN tblWorkArea ON tblLaborCore.[Labor Core] = tblWorkArea.[Labor Core]) INNER JOIN tblPosition ON tblWorkArea.Position = tblPosition.Postion) INNER JOIN tblSkills ON tblWorkArea.ID_WorkArea = tblSkills.ID_WorkArea

    WHERE (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Reading Schematics])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Wiring)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Wire Type])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Terminal Types])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[NEMA Ratings])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[UL 508])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Attention to Detail])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Lifting 50lbs])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Knowledge of Procedure])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Crimper)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Heat Gun])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Screwdriver)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Stripper)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Impact Drill])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Radial Saw])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Multimeter)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Torque Screwdriver/Wrench])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Tape Measure])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Vacuum)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Drill Press])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Jig Saw])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Troubleshooting Components])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Problem Solving])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Organization)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Large Panel])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Test Procedures])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Functional Testing])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Writing Test Procedures])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Material Management])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Set Meter Ability])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Tone Generator])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Megger Testing])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Network Tracer])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Components)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Fuses)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Heat Shrink Color Codes])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Proper Lug or Crimping])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Resistors Knowledge])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Oscilloscopes)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.Waveforms)<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblSkills.[Voltage Separation])<>0)) OR (((tblWorkArea.[Labor Core])=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxLaborCore]) AND ((tblWorkArea.Position)=[Forms]![SkillsMatrix]![boxPosition]) AND ((tblSkills.[Skill x_Stapling])<>0));
```

THANKS!

Comment: Ooops I messed up typing.  Actually have the boxWorkArea and it doesn't work

Comment: Alrighty. Posted above! No error message in this code. The problem comes up when I try storing the parameters in the combobox's through the form. Doesn't populate the Select Query

Comment: Dang, that didn't work. Do you think the problem lies in the properties of the combobox in the form?

Answer (score 0):

The trick I use is to build your query in a string, print the string to the immediate window, and visually verofy it's what you want. Then create a new query and use that string as the SQL. Access will tell you if there's a syntax error when you try to switch to Design View. If there are no syntax errors, try to run the query and see if you get what you want in your dataset.

In the string that you create, don't put the form references in quotes. Force VBA to resolve those field values before they are added to the string. When you do this, the SQL that you take to the query builder will have no form references in it.

PS> If any of the form references resolve to strings, be sure to quote those strings as you are building your SQL statement. This does not conflict with what I wrote above: you are literally encoding quotation marks into your SQL string.